# About catcodes and active characters

Tags: catcodes

I'm reading about catcodes and I want to play a bit with them. However, there's a point I don't really understand. When I want to define an active character, e.g., square brackets (`[` and `]`) I do the following:

```latex
\catcode`[ = \active 
\catcode`] = \active
```

and then

```latex
\def[{blah}
\def]{pfff}
```

so `[]` will print `blahpfff`. However, I cannot escape square brackets, e.g. in ConTeXt `\blank[argument]` or LaTeX `\includegraphics[key-value pairs]{cuteimage}`. I've tried

```
\let\amacro=[
\let\anothermacro=]
```

This works only to print the characters, not to replace square brackets in the commands below, e.g `\blank\amacro small\anothermacro`. Why isn't it working? Btw, I know catcodes are tricky, but I'm trying to learn about their working anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When one defines a command with an optional argument, say (simplified)

```
\newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{...}
```

where `...` is code to evaluate the material in the optional argument and in the mandatory one, the syntax for `\includegraphics` is either

```
\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}
```

or

```
\includegraphics{filename}
```

When `\includegraphics` is called, TeX looks at the next character; if it is `[`<sub>12</sub> (the subscript denotes the category code) one path is taken and basically a macro defined with delimited arguments is called. Otherwise another macro with a standard argument is called.

So if you change the category code of `[` to 13 (active), the call

```
\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}
```

will result in TeX *not* taking the first path, because a `[`<sub>12</sub> *doesn't* follow; instead the single argument macro is called, resulting in the active `[` to become the file name of the graphics to include.

Conclusion: *don't* make `[` active and neither `]`, of course.

---

Some more details. When you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][baz]{Something with #1 and #2}
```

the basic working is as follows. LaTeX defines *two* macros, namely `\foo` and `\\foo` (with a backslash in the name, I'll use `\sfoo` for better clarity in what follows); the former by

```
\def\foo{\@protected@testopt\foo\sfoo{bar}}
```

and the latter by

```
\def\sfoo[#1]#2{Something with #1 and #2}
```

The kernel macro `\@protected@testopt` is define by

```
% latex.ltx, line 885:
\def\@protected@testopt#1{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\@testopt
  \else
    \@x@protect#1%
  \fi}
```

In standard typesetting, the “true” branch is followed, so `\@testopt` is called

```
% latex.ltx, line 883:
\long\def\@testopt#1#2{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{#1[{#2}]}}
```

Here's where the testing for `[`<sub>12</sub> happens. In the replacement text of `\@testopt` there is `[`, which has already been tokenized at definition time, having category code 12. It won't recognize *any* other token to be the same as `[`. And `[`<sub>13</sub> is another token.

Comment: So, what I want to do isn't possible (?)

Comment: @JairoADelRio well in theory you could redefine `\includegraphics` to look for an optional argument delimited by active [] but you are pulling at a very tangled ball of string, each definition will break others and require further definitions, so it's not impossible, but perhaps rather adventurous.

Comment: @JairoADelRio Short answer: no. As David says, rather adventurous: you *might* regenerate the LaTeX format with ``\catcode`[=\active\catcode`]=\active`` in a strategic place, then see how many things break.

Comment: This makes me a bit sad.

Comment: @JairoADelRio or more simply just set the catcodes back to 12 locally before `\includegraphics`   something like  `{\catcode\`\[=12 \catcode\`\]=12 \includegraphics[...]{...}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That sounds more feasible. Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg I'll try as it seems funny. Thank you for your awesome explanation

Comment: @JairoADelRio you are changing a core syntax character, changing [ is brave but you should be pleased its even theoretically possible, changing `\ ` or `{` would definitely break everything.

Answer (score 4):

Broken down to the essentials/the basic ideas one can say:

For LaTeX-macros defined in terms of `\newcommand` that process optional arguments, in order to determine whether an optional argument is present, at some stage of processing `\kernel@ifnextchar`, the LaTeX 2ε wrapper around `\futurelet`, is used to test whether a token is present whose meaning equals the meaning of the explicit opening-square-bracket-character-token of category code 12(other).

Then a second macro is called by inserting a control-sequence-token into the token-stream whose name equals the name of the command defined via `\newcommand` but with a backslash prepended. E.g., with `\newcommand\foo[2][optional-default]{...}`, this will be `\\foo`.
The definition of that second macro corresponds to the definition provided with the corresponding `\newcommand`-directive. The control sequence token corresponding to this second macro (`\\foo`) is delimited by an explicit opening-square-bracket-character-token of category code 12(other). The first argument of this macro is delimited by an explicit closing-square-bracket-character-token of category code 12(other).

If the `\kernel@ifnextchar` test has revealed that there is no optional argument, then this second macro is called with a token sequence appended behind the corresponding control sequence token, which is structured as follows: opening-square-bracket-character-token of category code 12(other), default value, explicit closing-square-bracket-character-token of category code 12(other).

If the `\kernel@ifnextchar` test has revealed that there probably is an optional argument, this second macro is called without appending any additional tokens.

**With macros that process delimited arguments, the tokens that within the definition's parameter-text form the argument-delimiters cannot be replaced by other tokens of the same meaning.**

**This is because when TeX scans for argument-delimiters, TeX does "look" at tokens, not at the meanings of tokens.**

The `\\foo`-macro causes TeX to scan for argument-delimiters `[12` and `]12`.

With things like

```
\let\amacro=[
\let\anothermacro=]
\foo\amacro optional value \anothermacro...
```

you would require TeX not to "look" at tokens while scanning for argument-delimiters but to "look" at meanings of tokens.

In some situations you can do some `\uppercase`- or `\lowercase`-trickery—`\uppercase` and `\lowercase` leave the category-codes of explicit character-tokens unchanged while changing the character-codes, thus you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape, a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%% Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\advance\textwidth -2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.5cm
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\footskip=.5\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
{\normalfont
 \csname @tempdima\endcsname=.5\ht\strutbox
 \expandafter}\expandafter\advance\expandafter\footskip\the\csname @tempdima\endcsname
{\normalfont\expandafter}\expandafter\topskip\expandafter=\the\ht\strutbox
\pagestyle{plain}%
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\macrowithoptionalarg[1][default]{The things inside the parentheses are taken for the argument: (#1)}

\begin{document}

Test 1: \macrowithoptionalarg

Test 2: \macrowithoptionalarg[{non-default}]%

\begingroup
\catcode`[ = \active 
\catcode`] = \active
\def[{blah}
\def]{pfff}
%...
\begingroup
% catcode of ( is 12 and catcode of ) is 12.
\lccode`\(=`\[
\lccode`\)=`\]
% Now applying \lowercase to ( yields [ of catcode 12 and applying \lowercase to ) yields ] 
% of catcode 12, but be aware that AND gets lowercasd also:
Test 3: \lowercase{\endgroup\macrowithoptionalarg({[ AND ]})}%
%...    
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case `\edef` and ε-TeX's `\unexpanded` are allowed, you can apply `\string` for transforming active-`[` and active-`]` into their category-code-12-pendants:

```
\documentclass[landscape, a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%% Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\advance\textwidth -2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.5cm
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\footskip=.5\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
{\normalfont
 \csname @tempdima\endcsname=.5\ht\strutbox
 \expandafter}\expandafter\advance\expandafter\footskip\the\csname @tempdima\endcsname
{\normalfont\expandafter}\expandafter\topskip\expandafter=\the\ht\strutbox
\pagestyle{plain}%
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\baselineskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\macrowithoptionalarg[1][default]{The things inside the parentheses are taken for the argument: (#1)}

\begin{document}

Test 1: \macrowithoptionalarg

Test 2: \macrowithoptionalarg[{non-default}]%

\begingroup
\catcode`[ = \active 
\catcode`] = \active
\def[{blah}
\def]{pfff}
%...
\edef\scratchmacro{\unexpanded{\macrowithoptionalarg}\string[\unexpanded{[ and ]}\string]}%
Test 3: \scratchmacro
%...    
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm reading more possibilities in this question, but it seems like the attractive use for active definitions for characters is in math mode. There is support for that!

```
\begingroup
 \catcode`[ = \active 
 \catcode`] = \active
 \gdef[{blah}
 \gdef]{pfff}
\endgroup 
% catcodes are back to normal, but the definitions remain.
% special setting to use the definition in math mode
\mathchardef`[="8000
\mathchardef`]="8000
```

Now the problems with variant catcodes are gone, but the defined meanings are used in math formulas, but the plain characters are used in text mode.