# How to make brackets work like group separators?

Tags: catcodes, grouping

I know that the following is not something you are usually supposed to do, but I ask anyway: I am getting quite tired of the fact that TeX does not treat the content of brackets `[...]` as groups like `{...}`. This is getting annoying when writing math with lots of nested keyval interfaces, where stuff like

```
\command[key=\othercommand[otherkey=7]]
```

dies horribly. In other words, you have to wrap the key in braces:

```
\command[key={ \othercommand[otherkey=7] }]
```

I wonder: Does it *have* to be this way, or could you in principle make `[...]` behave like group separators (like `{...}`) and still make optional arguments like in `xparse` work? I am well aware that stuff like `$[a,b)$` would not work and would have to be replaced by `$\lbracket a,b)$`, but I’m fine with that.

I tried something like the below, which obviously failed horribly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldopenbracket=[

\let\oldclosebracket=]

\def\MakeBracketsStrict{
    \catcode`[=13
    \catcode`]=13
    
    \def[{\oldopenbracket\noexpand\bgroup}
    
    \def]{\oldclosebracket\noexpand\egroup}
}

\def\MakeBracketsNormal{
    \catcode`[=12
    \catcode`]=12
}

\begin{document}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\test{ mo }{we test #1 and #2}

\MakeBracketsStrict

\test{foo}[bar]

\MakeBracketsNormal

\test{foo}[bar]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try `\def\command[#1]{content for #1}` including brackets in your definition. Playing with catcodes in LaTeX is quite unsafe.

Comment: @JairoADelRio I need a general solution that works with `xparse` and similar packages. But I am aware that this might not be possible. Indeed, this can be unsafe, which is why I also want a command `\MakeBracketsNormal` to turn it off again.

Comment: [I made a similar question before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547218/about-catcodes-and-active-characters) (it seems not to have an easy solution). A better solution would be [using a keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package)

Comment: @JairoADelRio I am already relying on a keyval solution, namely the one in `expl3`. It does not solve the problem of nested equality signs when using brackets as optional arguments.

Comment: TeX doesn't treat `{...}` as a group when absorbing an argument; moreover `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are *no* substitute for `{...}` as argument delimiters. I'm not really understanding what you're after.

Comment: @egreg Maybe I am using the wrong vocabulary. What I want is for TeX to always treat `[...]` as pairs so that `\command[key=\othercommand[otherkey=7]]` would work. Right now, any key value package (including `l3keyval`) will fail because it found two equality signs inside the optional argument.

Comment: Use `\command[option={\anothercommand[anotheroption=...]}]`, with braces, if you want to embed a keyval into another one, in case it is possible

Comment: @JairoADelRio I know, as I also mentioned in the original post above. The whole point was to find out if this could be avoided somehow.